# React-native-google-places-autocomplete: passing dynamic string variables to a query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-places-api

I am trying to pass a dynamic country code to restrict search results as follows -:

```
let loc = 'de'

<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    placeholder="Search"
    autoFocus={true}
    onPress={(data, details = null) => {
        setSelection(data.description);
        }}
   query={{
       key: "key",
       language: "en",
       components:'country:loc'
       }}
   {...props}
   />
```

This works if I just pass a country code -- GB, DE, ZA, etc -- but it doesn't work if I try to pass in a variable. What should I do in order to be able to pass a dynamic variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a query string.

```js
let loc = 'de'

<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    placeholder="Search"
    autoFocus={true}
    onPress={(data, details = null) => {
        setSelection(data.description);
        }}
   query={{
       key: "key",
       language: "en",
       components:`country:${loc}`
       }}
   {...props}
   />
```